# Versions of GL and its device that don't display or required powers of 2 for the sprites

Tags: opengl, textures, graphics, platform, multiple-graphics-devices

From [**this question**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66522/is-it-possible-to-display-no-white-images-sprites-when-using-the-latest-android/66527?noredirect=1#comment119103_66527) aside from identifying possibilities of displaying images that don't needed to require powers of 2, what are the versions of GL that can actually display images even if don't needed the power of 2 size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's your answer.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/NPOT_Texture)

So it's been part of the core API since OpenGL 2.0, with a few hardware restrictions. As for OpenGL ES, [check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740077/can-opengl-es-render-textures-of-non-base-2-dimensions)